# MTB chain always jump after putting a new chain. It only skips on 4th and 5th gear cogs only

Tags: chain, sprocket, wear, skipping

I replaced my old chain with a new one. After changing the chain **I notice that standing pedaling uphill and flat surface in 4th or 5th gear the cogs will engage/disengage**. But when I put the old chain back on, the problem is gone. The cogs/cassette is 2 years old and I use it on both trail riding and XC.

Is the new chain the problem or do I need to replace the cassette/cogs when I install a new chain?

Comment: You might find the cassette has mated with the wear on the old chain and also needs to be replaced.  Excessive wear on the chain will also wear the cassette cogs

Comment: @Hursey that's almost certainly the correct answer.  If you wanted to write it in answer format i'd gladly upvote it

Comment: Okay will replace the cogs too, I will soon post the feedback here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the cassette has mated with the wear on the old chain and also needs to be replaced.
Excessive wear on the chain will also wear the cassette cog